# VBA/Userform - Transfer Value from a TextBox to Word with Bookmarks don't work

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform, bookmarks

I'm trying to create a userform that transfers the values of TextBoxes to a bookmarked location in a Word file but I'm getting an error. I tried some examples which I found on Google but I still getting the error.

I get the Error "VBA Object Doesn’t Support this Property or Method Error (Error 438)"

Am now at this point where I'm just trying a shorter macro which opens the Word file and should write "Test" into one bookmark:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
VorlagePfad = "D:\Temp\Testfile.doc"
DisplayAlerts = False
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordApp.Options.SaveInterval = 0

wordApp.Visible = True
Set wordDoc = wordApp.documents.Open(Filename:=VorlagePfad)

With wordDoc.Selection
    .Bookmarks("Zeile1").Range.Text = "Test"
End With

End Sub
```

The error ocures at the line

```
With wordDoc.Selection
```

I also tried this code and got also the same error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
VorlagePfad = "D:\Temp\Testfile.doc"
DisplayAlerts = False
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordApp.Options.SaveInterval = 0
wordApp.documents.Open VorlagePfad
wordApp.Visible = True
Set wordDoc = wordApp.documents.Open(Filename:=VorlagePfad)

wordApp.Bookmarks("Zeile1").Range.Text = "Test"

End Sub
```

I hope you can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: Part of your problem is that you have declared both wordApp and wordDoc as objects. This disables Intellisense which would have saved you from making such obvious mistakes. There is no benefit to using late binding when working across the Office apps anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the ".Selection". Like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
VorlagePfad = "D:\Temp\Testfile.doc"
DisplayAlerts = False
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordApp.Options.SaveInterval = 0

wordApp.Visible = True
Set wordDoc = wordApp.documents.Open(Filename:=VorlagePfad)

With wordDoc
    .Bookmarks("Zeile1").Range.Text = "Test"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry. Copy and Paste Error

Comment: No Prob. Works now :)